# Select query to retrieve results based on multiple values for a one column (AND condition)

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

There are three tables as follows

### Table 1 - Vehicle

Vehicle_Id PRIMARY KEY 
Name 
Serial_Number

### Table 2 - Propertyname

Property_Id PRIMARY KEY 
Name

### Table 3 - Property

Property_Id (FOREIGN KEY) references Property_Id from Propertyname table 
Value 
Id (FOREIGN KEY) references Vehicle_Id from Vehicle table

### Sample Data

### Table 1 - Vehicle

```
Vehicle_Id    Name    Serial_Number
```

```
1000        WagonR    Maruti-WagonR
```

```
1001        Estilo    Maruti-Estilo
```

```
1002        Zen       Maruti-Zen
```

### Table 2 - Propertyname

```
Property_Id    name
```

```
100            Mileage
```

```
101            FuelType
```

```
102            Country
```

### Table 3 - Property

```
Property_Id    Value    Id
```

```
100            50       1000
```

```
101            Petrol   1000
```

```
102            India    1000
```

```
100            35       1001
```

```
101            Diesel   1002
```

From the three tables we can see that each vehicle has a set of properties which are kept as rows in the Property table. This is done so that in case we add more properties to a vehicle we add a row entry for the vehicle rather than adding a column which is not feasible.

Now I have a UI where in i can search for vehicles based on their

1) Name, Serial_Number - These are available as columns in the Vehicle table & 
 
2) Mileage, FuelType, Country - These are the properties for the particular Vehicle

The user can enter any combination of values in 1) and 2) above to search through the list of vehicles.

Eg:- If the user enters Mileage as 50 and FuelType as Diesel, i should fetch results of vehicles which have Mileage as 50 AND FuelType as Diesel.

I tried the following SQL statement to do the same

```sql
select vh.Vehicle_Id, vh.name, pt.Property_Id, pn.name, pt.value
from property pt
inner join propertyname pn
on pt.Property_Id=pn.Property_Id
inner join vehicle vh
on vh.Vehicle_Id=pt.Id
and ((pn.Name='Mileage' AND pt.Value='50') AND (pn.Name='FuelType' AND pt.Value='Petrol'));
```

But i get zero results due to the AND condition on the single row result. But if i change the last AND condition to OR i get two results which match the criteria.

But I am trying to fetch Vehicles which matches both the properties matching.

I have tried using INTERSECT, inner join of two SQL statements etc. But couldnt get the result.

Could anyone suggest me the best way to search on two property name,value pairs which exist as rows and not columns to get the exact search results.

Comment: you need to reconsider the design of your database. the column named 'value' in the table-3 stores both the mileage and fuel type value. so its better to use two different columns for these values and then try.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Db design cannot be done at this point of time. Also properties for vehicle can get added anytime

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is the PropertyName can't be both 'Mileage' and 'FuelType' at the same time

You can find all the vehicles where the id is in the intersection of the two propertyNames like this

```
select Vehicle_Id, Vehicle.Name, Serial_Number, PropertyName.Name, Property.Value
from Vehicle
join Property on (Property.Id = Vehicle.Vehicle_Id)
join PropertyName on (PropertyName.Property_Id = Property.Property_Id)
where Vehicle_id in 
(select Id 
    from PropertyName 
    Join Property on (PropertyName.Property_Id = Property.Property_Id)
    where PropertyName.Name = 'Mileage' and Property.Value = '50'
 intersect 
 select Id 
    from PropertyName 
    Join Property on (PropertyName.Property_Id = Property.Property_Id)
    where PropertyName.Name='FuelType' AND Property.Value='Petrol'
 )
```

```
Vehicle_Id  Name    Serial_Number   Name    Value
1000    WagonR  Maruti-WagonR   Mileage 50
1000    WagonR  Maruti-WagonR   FuelType    Petrol
1000    WagonR  Maruti-WagonR   Country India
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways of doing it

I would do something like this

```
select vh.Vehicle_Id, pt_m.value as [Mileage], pt_f.value as [FuelType]
from vehicle vh
inner join propertyname pn_m ON pn_m.Name='Mileage'
inner join propertyname pn_f ON pn_f.Name='FuelType' 
inner join property     pt_m on pt_m.Property_Id=pn_m.Property_Id AND pt_m.Id = vh.Vehicle_Id
inner join property     pt_f on pt_f.Property_Id=pn_f.Property_Id AND pt_f.Id = vh.Vehicle_Id
```

You'll need two aliases for the property name table as you're joining to two properties and you'll similarly need two aliases for the property value

An advantage of this is that 
It can be quickly adapted to deal with vehicles where one of the properties isn't actually populated

```
select vh.Vehicle_Id, pt_m.value as [Mileage], pt_f.value as [FuelType]
from vehicle vh
left join propertyname pn_m ON pn_m.Name='Mileage'
LEFT join propertyname pn_f ON pn_f.Name='FuelType' 
LEFT join property     pt_m on pt_m.Property_Id=pn_m.Property_Id AND pt_m.Id = vh.Vehicle_Id
LEFT join property     pt_f on pt_f.Property_Id=pn_f.Property_Id AND pt_f.Id = vh.Vehicle_Id
```

Or even deal with inconsistend property names

```
select vh.Vehicle_Id, pt_m.value as [Mileage], pt_f.value as [FuelType]
from vehicle vh
left join propertyname pn_m ON pn_m.Name='Mileage'
LEFT join propertyname pn_f ON pn_f.Name IN ('FuelType','Fuel Type') 
LEFT join property     pt_m on pt_m.Property_Id=pn_m.Property_Id AND pt_m.Id = vh.Vehicle_Id
LEFT join property     pt_f on pt_f.Property_Id=pn_f.Property_Id AND pt_f.Id = vh.Vehicle_Id
```